# Cities API with images

Tags: rest, maps

Is there any API that can provide photos of city and data about that city (like latitude and longitude)? And it's not Google API
And also ANY free cities APIs links(especially with images) would be really helpful.
And also I want to know if there's any APIs that gives something like interesting facts about places or something like that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No more service Topia and Teleport free service.
That web site turns to charged service.

[image]

Using [TELEPORT PUBLIC APIS](http://developers.teleport.org/api/)

It provides the city image and location(latitude and longitude).

Example: Paris

#1 Find Paris id
https://api.teleport.org/api/cities?search=paris

```
"https://api.teleport.org/api/cities/geonameid:2988507/"
```

#2 Get location
https://api.teleport.org/api/cities/geonameid:2988507

```
    "location": {
        "geohash": "u09tvmqrep8np02g7x9y",
        "latlon": {
            "latitude": 48.85341,
            "longitude": 2.3488
        }
    }
```

#3 Get Image
https://api.teleport.org/api/urban_areas/slug:paris/images/

```
            "image": {
                "mobile": "https://d13k13wj6adfdf.cloudfront.net/urban_areas/paris-0ae0bb626e.jpg",
                "web": "https://d13k13wj6adfdf.cloudfront.net/urban_areas/paris_web-0a3c7314a5.jpg"
            }
```

[image: https://d13k13wj6adfdf.cloudfront.net/urban_areas/paris_web-0a3c7314a5.jpg]

They support API Explorer

http://developers.teleport.org/api/reference/

Comment: Topia retiring Teleport website: https://www.topia.com/topia-and-teleport/

Comment: Thanks, you for your information. I updated at the first statement.  You can use alternative web site at [OpenCage Geocoding API](https://opencagedata.com/), [Geonames API](https://www.geonames.org/export/web-services.html) or [Mapbox Geocoding API](https://docs.mapbox.com/api/search/geocoding/),
I will try it in soon.